# Prove that $\chi_l(K_{2,3})=2$

Tags: graph-theory, proof-verification, coloring

Prove that $\chi_l(K_{2,3})=2$

I know I asked question like this before, but something about this type still bugging me, so I tried more example in the book and I stumble again.

Let $G=K_{2,3}$. I know that $\chi_l(G) \geq \chi(G)=2$ because $G$ is bipartite. Now I let $U$ be the partite that contain 2 vertices, say $u_1,u_2$ and $W$ be the partite that contain 3 vertices $w_1,w_2,w_3$.

Let $\mathcal L=\{L(v):v\in V(G)\}$ be any collection of color list of size $2$.

Now I think I need to consider 2 big cases one of them is $L(u_1) \cap L(u_2) \neq \emptyset$ and another is $L(u_1) \cap L(u_2) = \emptyset$.

So in the big case when $L(u_1) \cap L(u_2) \neq \emptyset$.

Since $u_1$ and $u_2$ are independent, we can color them the same, and every vertex in $W$ has 2 neighborhood but they are only forbided from $1$ color, so each of them still have $1$ out of $2$ allowable color to choose.

For the second big case, consider following color lists

[image]

$L(u_1)$ and $L(u_2)$ doesn't have to be $(1,2)$ and $(3,4)$, they can be any thing as long as they are disjoint. Now I need to consider 2 cases.

Case 1: $c(u_1) =1$ if $c(u_2) =3$ then the color list in $W$ partite can be anything as long as they contain $2$ or $4$. And if $c(u_2)=4$ then he color list in $W$ partite can be anything as long as they contain $2$ or $3$;

Case 2: $c(u_1) =1$ if $c(u_2) =3$ then the color list in $W$ partite can be anything as long as they contain $1$ or $4$. And if $c(u_2)=4$ then he color list in $W$ partite can be anything as long as they contain $1$ or $3$.

I think the book is trying to show the second big case, but it still doesn't make alot of sense.

Comment: This is not the right kind of argument. If you want to prove $\chi_l(G)>k$ then it is sufficient to exhibit one single list assignment of length $k$ that forbids a proper coloring. If you want to prove $\chi_l(G)\leq k$ you need to prove that a proper $L$-coloring can be made for every possible list assignment of length $k$.

Comment: This is exactly how I feel, I've just write down the solution for the example in the book, and it's completely different from what you explained to me yesterday. I understand your explanation, but this solution from the book doesn't make any sense to me, so I just try to figure out what I'm missing

Comment: If you changed nothing, I think I did not read properly the first time and then I need to apologize. Now the proof looks fine: if $u_1$ and $u_2$ have a common color, you can use it and color the rest. When they have no common color you would need at least 4 vertices in the larger partite set to block all possibilities. This is fine.

Comment: no worry, I added a small part where $L(u_1)$ and $L(u_2)$ are not disjoint, I think the book skipped this part because the author think this is too obvious, this author does this a lot, and I often suffer from his/her assumption like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $L(u_1)\cap L(u_2)\ne\emptyset$, give $u_1$ and $u_2$ the same color; then you will have no problem coloring $w_1,w_2,w_3$.

If $L(u_1)\cap L(u_2)=\emptyset$, there are $4$ distinct sets of two colors which can be used to color $U$; choose one of these which does not coincide with any of the three lists $L(w_1),L(w_2),L(w_3)$.